# String comparison using pointers

Tags: c, strings, pointers

This piece of code works fine. But I'm wondering if it can be done in a more efficient way. More specifically, this part (`*(s1 + i)`) if it possible to force it to sequence through entire array character by character via pointer, for example, `*s1++`.

My task to do this function `compareStrings` without index array []:

```
int  compareStrings(const char  *s1, const char  *s2)
{
    int i = 0, answer;
    //  i - to sequence through array of characters
    // pointer to character string1 and character string2
    while (*(s1 + i) == *(s2 + i) && *(s1 + i) != '\0'&& *(s2 + i) != '\0')
    {
        i++;
    }

    if ( *(s1 + i) < *(s2 + i) )
        answer = -1;               /* s1 < s2  */
    else if ( *(s1 + i) == *(s2 + i) )
            answer = 0;                 /* s1 == s2 */
        else
            answer = 1;                 /* s1 > s2  */

        return answer;
```

But I want to change it to `s1++` and `s2++` instead of `*(s1 + i)` and `*(s2 + i)`. I've tried to implement this idea with pining an extra pointer to the beginning but I've failed.

> ```
> int  compareStrings(const char  *s1, const char  *s2)
> {
>   int answer;
>   char **i = s1, **j = s2;
>   // i to sequence through array of characters
>   while (*(i++) == *(j++) && *(i++) != '\0'&& *(j++) != '\0');
>
>   if (*i < *j)
>       answer = -1;               /* s1 < s2  */
>   else if (*i == *j)
>       answer = 0;                 /* s1 == s2 */
>   else
>       answer = 1;                 /* s1 > s2  */
>
>   return answer;
> }
> ```

Comment: Your braces and indentation are off. Please check that your code is posted as intended.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `*(s1 + i) == *s2 + i` is a typo and you mean `*(s1 + i) == *(s2 + i)`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't need pointers to character pointers at all:

```
int str_cmp(const char* s1, const char* s2)
{
    while (*s1 != '\0' && *s1 == *s2)
    {
        ++s1;
        ++s2;
    }

    if (*s1 == *s2)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return *s1 < *s2 ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Also, there is a bug in your second implementation: it returns 1 on `compareStrings("hello", "helloo")`, when the correct result is -1.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It would be more understandable if you write the test for end-of-string as "*s != '\0'".

Comment: You don't need to check that both `*s1` and `*s2` are non-null. Since you are checking that they are equal, you only need to check one of them for non-null. Although as written the compiler would probably optimize it to only do 1 check.

Answer (score 4):

There's another huge bug in your code which stems from a quirk of C (and C++):
Plain `char` can be either signed or unsigned.

Next, do you really want to normalize the return-values to one of `-1`, `0` and `1`, or is negative, zero, positive enough? The latter is what the standard does... and it's less work.

```
int compareStrings(const char* s1, const char* s2)
{
    while (*s1 && *s1 == *s2) {
        ++s1;
        ++s2;
    }
    return (int)(unsigned char)*s1 - (int)(unsigned char)*s2; // not normalized
    return *s1 == *s2 ? 0 : (unsigned char)*s1 < (unsigned char)*s2 ? -1 : 1; // normalized
}
```

(The code assumes that an `int` is bigger than a `char`.)

Comment: I've tried to implement your version of this function and it doesn't do the job that I need to at all. @Deduplicator

Comment: This wrong. If string s2 is shorter than s1 you read past the end of s2.

Comment: @Tony: How? That would mean they are different and thus stops the loop!

Comment: @Yellowfun: You mean you have to have your return-value normalized, or what?

Comment: Now it's working  fine! @Deduplicator

Comment: while (*s1 && *s1 == *s2) Does it mean ( I guess right)  (*s1 != '\0' && *s1 == *s2) ?@Deduplicator

Comment: @Yellow: That would be the same, yes.

Answer (score 3):

Remember when you learned that arrays are nothing but the pointer to the first element of the same array? You can do this the other way around too: `*(s1 + 1)` is equivalent to `s1[1]`.

In the second example take a look at how you resolve which pointer. `**i = s1` so will `*(i++)` be equal to `*(s1 + 1)`? Your debugger can tell you the details from here :)

Comment: It says "+  i 0x0018e25c {0x69726561 <Error reading characters of string.>} char * *
"

Comment: About it I know '*(s1 + 1) is equivalent to s1[1]'. :)

Comment: *"Remember when you learned that arrays are nothing but the pointer to the first element of the same array?"* If so, then you were taught incorrectly. :-) What you say here is true, but it's because arrays *decay* implicitly to a pointer to their first element. The two things are not equivalent as far as the language is concerned.

Comment: Agreed, it is an oversimplification.

Comment: Thank you. I thought pointer to array is a & address in the memory to that array[]. But we can reach to it from start to end through the first element and than incrementing with something like index.